# password confirmation rules in laravel failed

Tags: laravel

I am stuck with my problem of rules validation in laravel I don't know what is wrong

here is my blade code

```
 <div class="form-item form-group">
                <input name="password" id='password' type="password" value="" placeholder="Mot de passe" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-item form-group">
                <input name="confirm_password" id='confirm_password' type="password" value="" placeholder="Confirmation du mot de passe" required>
            </div>
```

And my register function

```
    protected function validator(array $data)
{
    var_dump($data);

    $validator = Validator::make($data, [
        'username' => 'required|max:255|unique:users,pseudo',
        'mail' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|between:8,255|confirmed'
    ]);

    $errors = $validator->errors();
    dd($errors);
    return $validator;

}
```

and the dd function return me that error

```
Illuminate\Support\MessageBag {#392 ▼
  #messages: array:1 [▼
    "password" => array:1 [▼
      0 => "The password confirmation does not match."
    ]
  ]
  #format: ":message"
}
```

I double check my password / confirm password and they are the same

Comment: `name='password_confirmation'`

Comment: @ChristopheHubert I can't use a different input name for the confirmation password ?

Comment: There is no easy way to use a different input name - you could create your custom rule if necessay

Comment: if password_confirmation must match password, then it must also have the same validation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the following name for your confirmation field, look at the doc(https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/validation#rule-confirmed)

> The field under validation must have a matching field of
>   foo_confirmation. For example, if the field under validation is
>   password, a matching password_confirmation field must be present in
>   the input.

So you need to change your code to:

```
    <div class="form-item form-group">
        <input name="password" id='password' type="password" value="" placeholder="Mot de passe" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-item form-group">
        <input name="password_confirmation" id='password_confirmation' type="password" value="" placeholder="Confirmation du mot de passe" required>
    </div>
```

If it is not possible to change the name of the input, you can use closure to create your own rule (https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/validation#using-closures)